# Thunderbird 3.0 - how to use ESC key to close new mail window

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

When reading an email, the ESC key can be used to close the window.  This doesn't work when you're composing an email.  Is there any way to do this?  This happened in T-Bird 2.x, as well, but I'm looking for a 3.0 solution.

Comment: This is for Ubuntu, BTW.  Sorry I failed to mention that.....

Comment: ESC closed a new mail window in thunderbird 2 ?  I am not sure I believe that.  Control+W or Alt+F4 will close the window.  1 more key, but less reach than esc anyway.

Comment: No, ESC failed to close a new window in 2.0 as well, but I am looking for a 3.0 solution (3.0 was new when I made this post).

Comment: @studiohack - why do you keep editing my posts and deleting my "Thanks"?  I find it rude.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte hello/thanks/regards/etc are discouraged here, I edit it out of just about everything I see, its not you.

Comment: @studiohack Citation? The salutations are discouraged, but I don't think there's anything wrong with "Thanks" at the end. If the question required lots of editing, I might understand your motive, but you edit a question _just_ to remove a polite word at the end?

Answer (score -1):

use **ALT + F4** instead. works for both, messages opened in new windows and indeed the 'write mail' window.

if you want a single key, you can of course remap **ALT + F4** (globally) with **[Keymapper](http://justkeepswimming.net/keymapper/default.aspx)** to any other key. however, i wouldn't recommend <kbd>ESC</kbd> for various reasons, i'm using <kbd>Pause</kbd> instead (which has an unwanted impact on NumLock but there's a [work around](http://justkeepswimming.net/keymapper/faq.aspx#q25)).

*Keymapper is open source freeware.*